# How to fix, httpacces didint recibe ID from URLs SEO-friendly

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get, slug

I am working with SEO compatible URLs, when I try to send my ID to my httpaccess, I receive a GET error: Array ().

This is a localserver, running in wamp, php 5 or 7, apache 2. In production works well, in my local not.

1.php

```
<?php 
    if(count($bibliotecas)>0){
        foreach($bibliotecas as $biblioteca){
            $url = '/biblioteca/'.$biblioteca->Id.'-'.$mainModel->url_slug($biblioteca->titulo);
            //$url = '/biblioteca?id='.$biblioteca->Id;
?>
    <h3><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">- <?php echo $biblioteca->titulo; ?> >></a></h3>
<?php 
        }
    } 
?>
```

2. httpaccess

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/ [L]
   RewriteRule ^admin/ - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?page=$2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+)/?$ $1.php?page=$2&ipp=$3 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
   ```
3. php 3 get reciber

   ```
   print_r("GET:");
   print_r($_GET);
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $biblioteca = $mainModel->getBiblioteca($id);
   ```

GET:Array ( )

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\biblioteca.php on line 11
>   Call Stack
>       Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1   0.0140  408568  {main}( )   ...\biblioteca.php:0

Comment: I did some tests

This is ok ->
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/$ biblioteca.php?id=$1 [L]

http://page.com/10-this-is-example


This dont work:

RewriteRule ^biblioteca/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/$ biblioteca.php?id=$1 [L]

http://page.com/biblioteca/10-this-is-example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]

If I change the rule for

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)B/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]

It's OK. B or X or C or some char.

Why?